# .htaccess redirection not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the following rules in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
#1. home page redirection
RewriteRule ^$ php/home.php [QSA,L]                                        

#2. Detect Non valid files (for menus)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

#3. append php/query.php                                                   
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ php/$1.php [QSA,L]
```

**UPDATE : The problem was that I did not have .htaccess in wp directory.**

This working fine but I have recently installed wordpress in
a sub folder of my website called wp. Listing the wordpress posts
works fine in my blog.php.

The user access the blog webpage by this url `http://mysite/blog`
then `rule #2` is executed.

The problem is that rule #2 and #3 is also fired when accessing the 
wordpress articles and admin portal. How do I prevent that from
happening in this situation, i need to access the below URLs.

> Internal Server Error

`http://mysite/wp/wp-admin`

> Internal Server Error

`http://mysite/wp/some-article`

**Folder structure**

```
|-mysite
  |- css
  |- .htaccess
  |- wordpress
    |- wp
    |- wp-admin
  |- php
    |- index.php
    |- blog.php
  |- js
```

Any help/advice much appreciated.

Thanks

**UPDATE : Everything is working now - This is my .htaccess file**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ php/home.php [QSA,L]                                                                                                                 
#WP articles
RewriteRule ^blog/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ wp/$1 [QSA,L]

#WP archives                     
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2})/?$ wp/$1 [QSA,L]

#WP search                                       
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=(.*)$
RewriteRule . wp/$/%1? [QSA,L]

#WP categories                
RewriteRule ^blog/category/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ wp/$1 [QSA,L]

#WP tags
RewriteRule ^blog/tag/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ wp/$1 [QSA,L]

#WP authors
#Insert authors redirect

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ php/$1.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

**I also experienced a 404 error when accessing my blog page - this was
caused by including the wp-blog-header.php file, the solution was to 
insert the following code in my blog.php and remove**
`include('wp/wp-blog-header.php)`

```
<?php
   require('./wp-config.php');
   $wp->init();
   $wp->parse_request();
   $wp->query_posts();
   $wp->register_globals();
?>
```

Comment: How about adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` condition?

Comment: You probably need to limit the #3 rule only to apply within php subdirectory like `RewriteRule ^php/(.*) php/$1.php [QSA,L]`.  You will also need to take a look at the .htaccess file which Wordpress uses to modify it to only make changes to wordpress directory.

Comment: did you try `RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog`

Comment: why isn't there a .htaccess file in the wordpress directory in your structure?

Comment: Hi. thanks for the comments I have added .htaccess in the wordpress folder and I can now access the URLS. I have updated the question with another issue I am now experiencing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, #2 is not a rule, it is a condition for executing the folowing rule (#3).

To fix your issue, there is multiple solutions, you can add for example a condition to not redirect anything that starts with wp/ :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ php/home.php [QSA,L]                                        

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?wp/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ php/$1.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I have nailed the problem now,
1. I neglected to create the .htaccess file in the wp dir
2. I updated my root .htaccess file (*See the question - Update section)

I'm marking your answer as accepted.